# allowing any valid MySQL user access to a particular table

Tags: mysql

I have a database table that I want all valid MySQL users to have access to (it's for tracking a particular set of statistics across multiple databases). Is there a way to do this?

I know you can wildcard hosts, but you don't appear to be able to wildcard usernames. Essentially, I want to do this:

```
REVOKE ALL PRIVILEGES ON  `database`.`table` FROM  ''@'%';
GRANT INSERT, UPDATE ON  `database`.`table` TO  ''@'%';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loop through all MySQL users in `mysql.user` table and grant privileges which you want:

```
mysql --skip-column-names -e "select user,host from mysql.user where host='%';" \
| grep -v root | \
while read account; do
    mysql -e "revoke all privileges on db.table from \
        '`echo $account | awk '{ print $1 }'`'@'%';"
    mysql -e "grant insert, update on db.table to \
        '`echo $account | awk '{ print $1 }'`'@'%';"
done
mysql -e "flush privileges;"
```

---

**UPDATE**

As I said in below comment, you can use [incron](http://incron.aiken.cz/) to monitor `/var/lib/mysql/mysql/user.MYI` and run the above script whenever an user is created.

Install incron and start it:

```
# /etc/init.d/incrond start
Starting Filesystem event daemon (incrond):                [  OK  ]
```

Create incron table for `mysql` user:

```
# incrontab -l -u mysql
/var/lib/mysql/mysql/user.MYI IN_MODIFY,IN_CLOSE_WRITE /var/lib/mysql/update_privileges.sh
```

When you create a new MySQL user, you will see the below in `/var/log/cron`:

```
incrond[13084]: (mysql) CMD (/var/lib/mysql/update_privileges.sh)
```

and the new user will be automatically granted `INSERT, UPDATE` privileges on `db.table`:

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Grants for testuser@%                                                                                   |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'testuser'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '*' |
| GRANT INSERT, UPDATE ON `db`.`table` TO 'testuser'@'%'                                                |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

I wonder whether there is a way to get the latest MySQL user and grant privileges for this one instead of doing for all users.

Comment: I know I can do that, but I'll have to remember to do it every time we create an account. I'd prefer something automatic.

Comment: You can use [incron](http://incron.aiken.cz/) to monitor `/var/lib/mysql/mysql/user.MYI` and execute the above script.

Comment: Just add quanta's script to the script you use for account creation. No need to remember anything then.

Answer (score 3):

MySQL does not support wildcards in user names as per mysql docs and there is no way other than using any script to add additional user privileges each time you add a new user.

Actually the grant statement without any user specified will grant access to the anonymous user account and you will need to set and use the password for the anonymous user account to access the table.

If you are trying to use this in a script I would rather suggest using a separate mysql user to gather information from that table rather than granting privilege & using individual mysql user credentials.

References:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/grant.html#grant-table-privileges

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/default-privileges.html

Comment: I've got a separate account for gathering, it's the inserting I'd rather be doing via wildcard permissions (as I'd prefer each app not need to use two separate db connections). Oh well. An odd omission! Thanks for your answer.